# how to autowire service in excelBuilder class in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

```
public class ExcelBuilder extends AbstractExcelView {

        @Autowired
        EkamtayinService ekamtayinService;//ekamtayin service is null

        @Override
        protected void buildExcelDocument(Map<String, Object> model, HSSFWorkbook workbook, HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
          //...
        }
 }
```

Comment: Is ExcelBuilder in spring context? Because I not see neither @Component annotation nor context configuration for you code snippet

Comment: yes it is, I just tried with @Component but doesn't help

Comment: Is EkamtayinService (or any subclass) in the context? Is it annotated with @Service or loaded using xml configuration?

Comment: yes,  of course it is anotated with @service

Comment: spring doesn't recognize ExcelBuilder i think, I can't autowire anything  there

Comment: It's looks like you don't have this bean in context, because in other case you've got exception when context had started. Check you context configuration, do you turn on annotation scan for you beans? for related packages, which contains you bean? How have you configured spring context?

Comment: I can autowire in ekamtayinServiceImpl and ekamtayinDaoImpl, but cant do it here, everything is well configured

Comment: how can I do that spring recognises my ExcelBuilder?

Comment: You need to supply a MCVE. You must annotate `ExcelBuilder` with `@Component`, _and_ you need to `ComponentScan` the package that contains `ExcelBuilder` or ditch `@Component` and explicitly configure `ExcelBuilder` as a Spring bean.

Comment: this is my componenent scan @ComponentScan(value = "am.taxservice.soldierPayment")

Comment: ExcelBuilder is indide  am.taxservice.soldierPayment.view package